# Sigma additivity of signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

Suppose we have $(X, M, v)$ as a measure space. $v$ is a signed measure, then it also satisfies sigma additivity, i.e.

> If {$E_j$} is a sequence of disjoint sets in $M$ , then $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)=\sum_1^\infty v(E_j)$

What is the meaning of the series on the right-hand side? **Can I always write it as the limit of finite summation?**

I know a signed measure can only attain at most one of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.
So, if at least one of the $v(E_i)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$, then I can do it.

If all the $v(E_i)$s are finite, then $\sum_1^\infty |v(E_j)|$ must converge ($+\infty$ or finite).

1. If it is finite, then the original series is absolute convergent, so convergent, so I can also write it as a limit of finite summation.
2. If it is infinite, then **can I still write the original series as the limit of finite summation?** In this case, the limit may not exist, writing in this way makes no sense to me.

Comment: An infinite sum is always the limit of finite sums.

Comment: I think it can be written in this way only when it has limit, no matter plus infinity, finite number or negative infinity?

Comment: For example, when $v$ is a measure, then infinite sum can be written as the limit of finite sum because the limit always exist!

Comment: The infinite sum is, by definition, the limit of finite partial sums. As you said, the limit may not exist - but when we write $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j) = \sum_1^\infty v(E_j)$, the author means that the limit of finite partial sums on the RHS exists and equals $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)$.

Comment: A series is a sequence of the partial sums. That sequence may not converge but the sum gives you the correct sequence.

Comment: A signed measure is not necessarily $\sigma$ additive.